# Magento 2 require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Script error for: jquery-ui-modules/widget

Tags: magento2, frontend-error, jquery-ui

I recently installed Magezon Pagebuilder plugin.
It works perfect and everything, however when I add Sliders or Carousel I get this 2 errors:

```
require.js:1895 GET http://dev.emall.com.mx/pub/static/version1606325200/adminhtml/Transom/ChangeAdminLogo/en_US/jquery-ui-modules/widget.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)


Uncaught Error: Script error for: jquery-ui-modules/widget
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)
```

I have tried this solutions:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy 
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Delete var/cache and var/view_preprocessed.

clean cache

I checked my .htaccess and seems to be in order, in pub/static and pub/media.

I have used all solutions I know, what could it be?

Thanks!

Comment: this seems like a third party issue. did you check its compatibility with the Magento version you are using?

Comment: I see this in the module: Compatibily Community Edition: 2.0.x, 2.1.x, 2.2.x, 2.3.x, 2.4.x

Comment: remove var/cache and pub/static contents except .htaccess file then try to reinstall the plugin. if still won't work. try to install the plugin with fresh installation of Magento. It might be that proper file permissions are not set.

Comment: no luck my friend, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered what was causing the problem in case you have the same error with this Magezon PageBuilder module.

in app/code/Magezon/PageBuilder/view/base/web/js/slider.js the jquery ui-modules are defined like this:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery-ui-modules/widget',
    'Magezon_Core/js/owl.carousel.min'
]
```

I don't know if it's my Magento 2.3.1 version, but I changed it for this , and it worked.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui-modules/widget',
    'Magezon_Core/js/owl.carousel.min'
]
```

Just change jquery-ui-modules for jquery/ui-modules.
The errors will disappear and sliders will work fine.

Greetings!

Comment: in my case thi 
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery-ui-modules/widget',
this declaration is every where in magento 2

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2.2.7 i have set:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'Magezon_Core/js/owl.carousel.min'
]
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm running 2.2.9 and had 'jquery-ui-modules/widget' which I've replaced with 'jquery/ui'. Voila, it works!